# Initialiser element is not a constant - using the static variable inside the loop

Tags: c

I am trying out examples on mixed declarations. Why does this static int x = j + i give the error "initialiser element is not a constant"?

Do static variables always have to be declared with a constant and not assigned with variables?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
        int i = 1;
        int j;
        for(j = 2 * i ; j < 20; j++){
                static int x = j + i;
                printf("\n x = %d \n",x);
                x += 2;
                printf("\n i = %d \n",i);
                printf("\n &x = 0x%x \n",(unsigned int)&x);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you think about what a static variable does and how it behaves, then you will suddenly realize that initializing it with a non-constant value doesn't make sense.

Comment: Nick . you answered with your comments. I'm waiting to vote for your post ;

Answer (score 2):

Scalar variables may be initialized when they are defined, by following the name with an equals sign and an expression:
   `int x = 1;`
   `char squota = '\'';`
   `long day = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L; /* milliseconds/day */`

For external and static variables, the **initializer must be a constant expression**; **the initialization is done once**, conceptionally before the program begins execution. For automatic and register variables, the initializer is not restricted to being a constant: it may be any expression involving previously defined values, even function calls.

automatic variables are local function variables.
From K&R chapter 4.

A constant expression is evaluated at compile time, not run time, and can be used in any place that a constant can be used. The constant expression must evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for that type.